# Ruby "complex" hash manipulation

Tags: ruby, hash

Trying to consolidate some data before sending out to the database.

Given the following array of hashes:

```
[
  {
    "id" => "A",
    "name" => "Batman",
    "entry" => "1"
  },
  {
    "id" => "A",
    "name" => "Batman",
    "entry" => "2"
  },
  {
    "id" => "B",
    "name" => "Superman",
    "entry" => "1"
  }
]
```

How can I transform it into:

```
[
  {
    "id" => "A",
    "name" => "Batman",
    "entries" => ["1","2"]
  },
  {
    "id" => "B",
    "name" => "Superman",
    "entries" => ["1"]
  }
]
```

Thank you

Comment: The format you wrote is not an array.

Comment: This is a fairly simple reduce(/inject) operation; have you checked the documentation on Enumerable#reduce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [
        {
          "id" => "A",
          "name" => "Batman",
          "entry" => "1"
        },
        {
          "id" => "A",
          "name" => "Batman",
          "entry" => "2"
        },
        {
          "id" => "B",
          "name" => "Superman",
          "entry" => "1"
        }
       ]

out = data.group_by{|h| [h['id'], h['name']]}.values.map do |hs|
  hs.first.merge({'entry' => hs.map{|h| h['entry']}})
end

p out
#=> [{"id"=>"A", "name"=>"Batman", "entry"=>["1", "2"]}, {"id"=>"B", "name"=>"Superman", "entry"=>["1"]}]
```